# Not allowed to load local resource: in asp.net webform image cannot be Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Not allowed to load local resource: **file:///C:/users/bitcode-system-2/documents/visual%20studio%202015/Projects/Job-Posting-Website/Job-Posting-Website/Images/25498212_10155939376724919_7127758539025037198_n.jpg636510209049142432.jpg**
Image cannot load on WebPage Properly

Comment: Try change "visual%20studio%202015" to "visual studio 2015"

Comment: you can't access local files from a browser unless you're just running your page in a local context. You need to provide a proper URL to the image

Comment: s is path                 
                    image.ImageUrl = s.ToString();
                    image.Visible = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName); string filePath =("Images/"+FileName+ DateTime.Now.Ticks+".jpg"); FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath.ToString()));

### Actual Syntax is . this ..you used not proper url